# Using Mysql and PHP to query data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have 10 tables that have all the same fields in. These are :

```
LeadID|customernumber|salevalue|Marketingcode
```

Each table is named: custom_1 up to custom_10

I then have a master_table that has the below fields in:

```
LeadID|Eventdate|Status|ListID
```

The leadID is the key that will link the custom_ tables to the master table.

The listID in the master table is the number of the custom table (i.e customer_2 etc )

I am just learning PHP and cannot work out how to take the leadid and pull back all data linked to that leadid in all of the custom tables to then perform the calculations I need.

I want to end up with an output that gives me by date or date range:

```
Date| Marketingcode| Count of sales | sum of salevalue
```

Would be extremely grateful for any help you can give.

Thanks

Comment: Normalize your "custom_1 up to custom_10" to one table (and add ListID column with according values). Then join it with master table using 2-columns equality expression.

Comment: can you add your php files of you have done at the time ?